# Why is Super Saiyan Blue (Goku) more powerful than Super Saiyan God (Goku)?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I watched the series earlier. I now joined the Stack Exchange and found this forum so I searched about this but could not find an appropriate answer. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is already answered in the wikia page of *Dragon Ball*.

The [Super Saiyan Blue](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Blue) is a *combination of the power* of [Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan) and [Super Saiyan God](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_God).

Or,

Super Saiyan Blue is using the power of a God {God ki} and transforming to a Super Saiyan.

Therefore, *Super Saiyan Blue has much greater power than Super Saiyan God*.